Seeing yellow lines below django.shortcuts in VS CODE
I'm new in Django, And I'm seeing yellow lines below everything I include from Django like django.db import models Seeing yellow lines on Django.db and model also in app.djando In all of the Django imported stuff The food is working totally fine but
whenever i see a video there is nothing like this And as much as I know it generally shows when you haven't installed a Library or package
When I hover on it, it shows
"Import "django.shortcuts" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
(module) shortcuts"
I have tried like many solutions shown in Google result and also on chatgpt like

Reinstalling the Django
checking the typho mistakes
Reinstalling python
Updating all two latest version
But I'm unable to find a solution

